# Replacing underscore "_" with backslash-underscore "\_" in an R string

Tags: r, regex, stringr

Q: How can I replace underscores "_" with backslash-underscores "_" in an R string? I'd prefer to use the `stringr` package.

Also, can anyone explain why line 5 below fails to get the desired result? I was almost certain that would work.

```
library(stringr)
s <- "foo_bar_baz"
str_replace_all(s, "_", 5) # [1] "foo5bar5baz"
str_replace_all(s, "_", "\_") # Error: '\_' is an unrecognized escape in character string starting ""\_"
str_replace_all(s, "_", "\\_") # [1] "foo_bar_baz"
str_replace_all(s, "_", "\\\_") # Error: '\_' is an unrecognized escape in character string starting ""\\\_"
str_replace_all(s, "_", "\\\\_") # [1] "foo\\_bar\\_baz"
```

Context: I'm making a LaTeX table using `xtable` and need to sanitize my column names since they all have underscores and break LaTeX.

Comment: `str_replace_all(s, "_", "\\\\_") # [1] "foo\\_bar\\_baz"` is exactly what you want since `\\\` figure a literal backslash. (You need to understand the difference between a string and the way it is represented).

Comment: You're right. It's working. Still confusing to me. But it's working. Thx for the pointer.

Comment: In this case, upvote my comment, I like people that upvotes my comments, but I like bears, badgers, rabbits, poneys and unicorns too. Birds are my friends.... as dolphins.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is all much easier. Replace *literal* strings with *literal* strings with the help of `fixed("_")`, no need for a regex.

```
> library(stringr)
> s <- "foo_bar_baz"
> str_replace_all(s, fixed("_"), "\\_")
[1] "foo\\_bar\\_baz"
```

And if you use `cat`:

```
> cat(str_replace_all(s, fixed("_"), "\\_"))
foo\_bar\_baz>
```

You will see that you actually have 1 backslash in the result.

Comment: Cool, didn't know about this. Not intuitive to me why `fixed` would be applied to the pattern rather than the replacement. But it works :)

Comment: Then why use `stringr`, use `gsub` - `gsub("_", "\\_", s, fixed=TRUE)`. It is more intuitive :)