# Escape underscore (\\_) not escaping correctly

Tags: r, kable

I'm using kableExtra with a github_document and my underscore is not outputting correctly.

Before I tried to escape it, the table was outputting as so:
[image: table with backslashes]

I then tried to see if I could get rid of the backslashes by escaping the underscore with no luck.
I've tried to escape with `\_` `\\_` and `\\\\_` all of which don't give me the desired result. Using:

- `\_` R says that it isn't a valid escape command
- `\\_` prints `\_` in my table
- `\\\\_` prints `\\\_` in my table.

My YAML:

```
---
output: github_document
always_allow_html: true
---
```

Chunk options:

```
knitr::opts_chunk$set(
  collapse = TRUE,
  comment = "#>",
  fig.path = "man/figures/README-",
  out.width = "100%"
)
```

sample code:

```
names_table <- data.frame(name = c("Heat Index", "Heat Index Extreme Caution", "Heat Index Dangerous", "Temperature over the 95th percentile"), df_name = c("heat\\_index", "heat\\_index\\_ec", "heat\\_index\\_dan", "temp\\_over\\_95\\_pctl"), calculation = c("Heat index calculation", "Temperature between 90-102F", "Temperature between 103-124F", "Temperature exceeds historic 95th pctl"))

names_table %>% 
  knitr::kable(col.names = c("Variable Name",
                      "Column Name",
                      "Variable Calculation"),
        escape = TRUE,
        format = "html") %>% 
  kable_styling(bootstrap_options = c("striped", "hover", "condensed"),
                full_width = F,
                position = "center") %>%
  column_spec(3, width = "20em")
```

If I run the code *without* `kable_styling`, it *runs* correctly (i.e. the output is what I want) but if I *knit* the document, my table still prints with an unwanted backslash.

I've scoured SO with no luck of finding anything to help, but maybe I'm misunderstanding some help somewhere.

Edit: added image of problem, added more information about how the problem arose.

Comment: Underscore is a word and not a special character hence no need to escape it

Comment: `_` is NOT a special character but rather a word. you do not have to escape it

Comment: Interesting - kable is adding a backslash in front of my underscores without me trying to escape them which is why I went down this rabbit hole.

Comment: In LATEX `_` IS a special character, in R, it is NOT.  Sorry again DO you want it escapped or NOT? Your question is not clear. otherwise do not escape it

Comment: Gotcha thanks for clarifying. The problem arose when I knit my table the first time. I did not add backslashes in front of my underscores, but the table that resulted had backslashes in it. The observations in my `column_names` should be in the table written as `heat_index` `heat_index_dan` etc. But instead when I knit the document they came out as `heat\_index` `heat\_index\_dan` which is why I tried to escape them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find a workaround for my problem by saving the table as an image and inserting the table into my markdown as an image. It doesn't solve the issue of the output of `github_document` adding backslashes in front of underscores. Continuing from above:

```
kable_out <- names_table %>% 
  knitr::kable(col.names = c("Variable Name",
                      "Column Name",
                      "Variable Calculation"),
        escape = TRUE,
        format = "html") %>% 
  kable_styling(bootstrap_options = c("striped", "hover", "condensed"),
                full_width = F,
                position = "center") %>%
  column_spec(3, width = "20em")

save_kable(kable_out, "man/figures/kable_table.png", zoom = 5)
# zoom preserves image quality

knitr::include_graphics("man/figures/kable_table.png")
```

Answer (score 1):

See [here]([https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40351980/replacing-underscore-with-backslash-underscore-in-an-r-string]!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40351980/replacing-underscore-with-backslash-underscore-in-an-r-string%5D!), the usage of `stringr::fixed` and `\\_`, like this:

```
> library(stringr)
> s <- "foo_bar_baz"
> str_replace_all(s, fixed("_"), "\\_")
```

Comment: Hi, While this answer shows how we may replace characters, I don't immediately see how it addresses the original question. The issue arose when trying to knit a document. To be helpful, I think you answer would need to address the problem in that context.

Comment: As @onyambu mentioned: In LATEX `_` IS a special character, in R, it is NOT. I needed to escape it to create a latex table with `kable` inside Rmarkdown. Using that approach (`fixed("_")`) I was able to `knit` the Rmd to pdf with the table in latex format. I thing that option is solving the question.

Comment: Based on what you say, I think it would be a good idea for you to expand your answer to show provide more detail.